I am trying to assign individual number in an integer variable to a dynamic array in c. But for some reason it is not working
So I am trying to test out this code which doesn't seem to work as intended. I have not used C before and I am doing this for CS50 (those who are familiar its week 1).
So basically, I have an integer, lets say 12345. I am trying to assign the first number (1) to index 0 of the dynamic array and so forth.
However the code isn't working so is there something I need to know about arrays that I have missed?
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdlib.h>




int countDigits(int num) //this gives the length of the integer
{
    int count = 0;

    while(num != 0)
    {
        count++;
        num = num/10;
    }
    return count;
}


int main(void)
{
    int num = get_long("num: ");

    int length = countDigits(num);

    printf("%d \n", length); //printing test to see if it has returned the correct length, and it does

    int* array; //declare the pointer

    array = (int*) malloc(length * sizeof(int));  // declare the dynamic array

    for(int i = 0; i < length ;i ++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);  //print out the array first to see the content
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(int k = 0; k < 2 ; k ++)
    {
        array[length] = (num % 10);  //this is just a testing enviroment for me to assign numbers (i am currently keeping it two digits)
        num = num/10;
        length --;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 2 ;j ++)
    {
        printf("%d \n", array[length]);  //once again i print out the content and see if its correct and its not
    }
}


I type in 12, it prints the length 2 which is correct, then it prints the array before assignment which is presumably correct, but it still returns zero at the end when it should theoretically give 1 and 2.

When you allocate memory with malloc, the memory isn't initialized in any way. All of the memory will have indeterminate (read: garbage) data.

How should I approach this problem then?

Also, why do you allocate length elements, but only use two of those elements? And as I mention in my answer, be careful if the user only gave a single-digit value as input.

its for another project where I am trying to implement luhn's alogrithm for credit card validation. My approach was to get the length of the credit card and declare an array of that length. Then since I'm using the modulus operator, by using length, it wont be inversed.

Then I suggest you work with strings and characters instead of numbers. First of all, CC-numbers usually have more digits that can be handled by a single int. Secondly, using int you will loose leading zeros.

Are you sure that int num = get_long("num: "); isn't mixing types?

is it possible to do calculations with strings and characters in C? (Python does not)

@user24446695 Yes it's possible. C guarantees that you can do e.g. '3' - '0' and get the integer value 3. So to get the integer equivalent of a character in a string str you use str[i] - '0'. But please don't be conservative when creating the string (using a plain array of characters), use a size that you know you will never get. Then you don't have to worry about things like the string terminator. Say at least 32 characters.

Uh you're right, I forgot to change that when I was trying to test this (copy and pasted from another file. )

Oh wow, that is actually really nice. I will definitely switch around and use it. Thank you for your help!

printf("%d \n", array[length]); You probably want to either modify length or use j in some way unless you want to print the same index multiple times.

array[length] = (num % 10); will break the array bounds. The length in the first iteration is the number of elements, and you may only index from [0] to [length-1].

In the last loop, should printf("%d \n", array[length]);  be printf("%d \n", array[j]); ?

I am so dumb actually, you guys have all noted the silly mistakes I made. In my defence, I haven't drank my cup of coffee. (Thank you very much!)

Don't be too clever... If the problem is Luhn's Algorithm, the data is CC "numbers". These are presumed to be "human-sized" (ie: not 328 digits long). Simpler code would use a compile-time array of, say, 32 or 64 bytes, avoiding the complexities of heap allocation. (You forgot to free() the block.) Make use of the 8Mb (or 1Mb) of stack that is given to your program and write simpler "KISS" code...

The main problem is this assignment:
array[length] = (num % 10)

When the loop starts, you assign to an element that is out of bounds of the array. Going out of bounds of an array (fixed or dynamic) leads to undefined behavior.
Either use lenght - 1 as index, or --length. But in both cases you need to explicitly check that length > 0.
Then when you print the contents of the array, you only print one single element, which might or might not be valid.

If you only want to use two elements of the array, first of all make sure that your loops doesn't go out of bounds (use k < 2 && k < length as condition). Then simply use k as the index:
array[k] = (num % 10)


To be more explicit, don't print values right after calling malloc. And the loops to set values and print the values should look like this:
for(size_t k = 0; k < 2 && k < length; k++)
{
    // Do what your loops needs to do
    // Using the variable k as the index
}


I have done that now, it is indeed assigning numbers now but its showing that 1 and 1 has been stored and not 1 and 2 (the test data is 12). Also out of curiosity since I use python more, how does malloc actually work (yes I have read over some guides), I thought it was similar to declaring an array in python with 2 indexes

@user24446695 malloc(length * sizeof(int)) will allocate enough bytes for length number of int elements. And as all arrays in C the index is zero-based, so you have element indexes from 0 to length - 1.

So essentially you're saying that if the length was 2, it would allocate enough bytes for two int elements or literally the number 2?

@user24446695 Enough for two elements. And the valid indexes will be 0 and 1.
